# Snakemake error : MissingInputException in rule bwa_map

Tags: python, conda, snakemake

I am trying to create a simple Snakemake workflow and I am having some issues. My file generates the following errors:

```py
MissingInputException in rule bwa_map in file /home/muhammad/snakefile, line 1:
Missing input files for rule bwa_map:
output: mapped_reads_allsamples/barcode01.fastq_runid_3c11097ede35a7f061046232b44e0228595f2f23_0.bam
affected files:
MinION_1stRun_fastq_pass/guppy_demult/fastq_all_barcodes/barcode01.fastq_runid_3c11097ede35a7f061046232b44e0228595f2f23_0.fastq`
```

My snakefile content is:

```py
rule bwa_map:
    input:
         genome = "miniconda3/data/G6PD_RefSeqGene_FASTA.fa",
     samples = "MinION_1stRun_fastq_pass/guppy_demult/fastq_all_barcodes/barcode01.fastq_runid_3c11097ede35a7f061046232b44e0228595f2f23_0.fastq"
    output:
        sample_bams = "mapped_reads_allsamples/barcode01.fastq_runid_3c11097ede35a7f061046232b44e0228595f2f23_0.bam"
    shell:
        "bwa mem {input} | samtools view -Sb - > {output}"`
```

I have these folders/files in my main directory:

```bash
/home/muhammad/miniconda3/
/home/muhammad/MinION_1stRun_fastq_pass/
/home/muhammad/ont-guppy/
/home/muhammad/snakefile
```

Please share your kind comments how can I fix this error.

I tried changing the directories in the input however its not working.

Comment: **I have these folders/files in my main directory**

/home/muhammad/miniconda3/
/home/muhammad/MinION_1stRun_fastq_pass/
/home/muhammad/ont-guppy/
/home/muhammad/snakefile

Comment: Does you input file `MinION_1stRun_fastq_pass/guppy_demult/fastq_all_barcodes/barcode01.fastq_runid_3c11097ede35a7f061046232b44e0228595f2f23_0.fastq` exist? If it does, make sure there is not typo in the path/name